# Thread that never ends

Tags: java, multithreading, io, blockingqueue

Here is my code:

```
   public class BigFileReader implements Runnable {
    private final String fileName;
    int a = 0;

    private final BlockingQueue<String> linesRead;
    public BigFileReader(String fileName, BlockingQueue<String> linesRead) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.linesRead = linesRead;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //since it is a sample, I avoid the manage of how many lines you have read
            //and that stuff, but it should not be complicated to accomplish
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("E:/Amazon HashFile/Hash.txt")));
            String str = "";

            while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                linesRead.put(str);
                System.out.println(a);
                a++;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Completed");
    }
}





public class BigFileProcessor implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<String> linesToProcess;
    public BigFileProcessor (BlockingQueue<String> linesToProcess) {
        this.linesToProcess = linesToProcess;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String line = "";
        try {
            while ( (line = linesToProcess.take()) != null) {
                //do what you want/need to process this line...
                String [] pieces = line.split("(...)/g");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}





public class BigFileWholeProcessor {
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 2;
    public void processFile(String fileName) {

        BlockingQueue<String> fileContent = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
        BigFileReader bigFileReader = new BigFileReader(fileName, fileContent);
        BigFileProcessor bigFileProcessor = new BigFileProcessor(fileContent);
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
        es.execute(bigFileReader);
        es.execute(bigFileProcessor);
        es.shutdown();

    }
}
```

This code is fine, but with a major problem. That is, the thread never ends! Even the entire process is completed, I can still the program is alive. What is wrong here?

Comment: What evidence do you have that it never ends? How are you submitting the `Runnable`?

Comment: Before starting it, setDeamon(true).

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but `a++` is [probably] not thread-safe. You should use `AtomicInteger` instead.

Comment: @yshavit there is no issue with `a++` here since only one thread is ever reading/writing it's value.

Comment: @mattb True, but the fact that `a` is a field, and not a local variable, suggests that somebody else is going to read it at some point. Absent some other synchronization (`a` being volatile, a `Thread.join`, etc), that read will not be thread-safe. The easiest thing would probably be to make it `volatile` (not `AtomicInteger` as I originally wrote). But that is assuming, of course, that this Runnable instance isn't running on two threads -- if it is, even `volatile` isn't enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BlockingQueue.take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) will block until an element is available:

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available.

So after BigFileReader has finished reading the input file and placing lines on the BlockingQueue, BigFileProcessor will wait forever in the `take()` method for new input.

You might want to find a way to signal to BigFileProcessor that there will be no more input ever put on the BlockingQueue, possibly by adding [a sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) to the queue or finding some other way to tell BigFileProcessor to stop calling `take()`.

An example of the sentinel approach:

```
public class BigFileReader implements Runnable {
    public static final String SENTINEL = "SENTINEL"; //the actual value isn't very important
    ...

    while((str=br.readLine())!=null) {
        linesRead.put(str);
    }
    //when reading the file is done, add SENTINEL to the queue
    linesRead.put(SENTINEL);
}

//inside BigFileProcessor...
while ( (line = linesToProcess.take()) != null) {
    // check if value in queue is sentinel value
    if (line == BigFileReader.SENTINEL) {
         //break out of the while loop
         break;
    }
    //otherwise process the line as normal
}
```

Another approach could be to use [the overload of `poll` that takes a timeout value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) instead of `take()`, and have the logic be that BigFileProcessor breaks it's loop if it can't read anything from the queue for more than N seconds, etc.

Comment: This is the first time I am dealing with this. I have no idea about what to do. Can you show me please?

Answer (score 0):

BlockingQueue, as its name suggests, is blocking. Meaning once you execute queue.take() the thread hangs until there is something in the queue to take. In order to terminate the thread, you need to use queue .isEmpty() to know if there are still any messages in the queue. I suggest sending an End Of File message once you finished reading the file in order to know when to exit the loop.